# WHY DOES swift UIPickerView fire multiple calls to delegates numberOfComponents & numberOfRowsInComponent?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Is is my output that prints each time a delegate is called.

Why multiple:  numberOfComponents & numberOfRowsInComponent ?

```
open_plot_picker()...
numberOfComponents: 1
numberOfComponents: 1
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfComponents: 1
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
titleForRow: raw heart beat only    row 0
titleForRow: filtered heart beat only    row 1
open_plot_picker() done.
select_plots_UIButton() done.
numberOfComponents: 1
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
titleForRow: raw heart beat only    row 0
titleForRow: filtered heart beat only    row 1
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
titleForRow: raw heart beat only    row 0
titleForRow: filtered heart beat only    row 1
titleForRow: heart rates only    row 2
titleForRow: raw HB and HR     row 3
titleForRow: filtered HB and HR    row 4
titleForRow: filtered and raw HB    row 5
numberOfRowsInComponent: 6
titleForRow: raw heart beat only    row 0
```

Comment: How often are you calling `reloadData`?

Comment: @koen, you mean `reloadAllComponents()`? reloadData is a table view/collection view method.

Comment: While I’m curious to know the underlying reason, your code should be absolutely insensitive to this. If your delegate’s methods have a side effect that allowed you to notice this in the first place, then I think it’s a fair indication that something is fishy.

Comment: I don't call either reloadData or reloadAllComponents.  Should I.

Answer (score 2):

You should not care how often your delegate methods are called. It looks like it asks your delegate for the number of rows over and over. Just make sure that code is performant and don't worry about it.

Comment: That's good to know and alleviates all anxiety.  But, my question is, and subsequent to Duncan's elucidation, why does iOS call multiple times?